# How to add an album cover to an mp3 stream using FFmpeg?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, mp3, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm having a bit of an issue and I'd really appreciate it if I could get some insights.

**What I am trying to do is to add an album cover to the mp3 file that will be downloaded from the front-end.**

## Context

I'm downloading a video stream from YouTube and converting it to mp3 using `fluent-ffmpeg`.
To get the video I use the `ytdl` npm module.

I then pipe this stream to the front-end.

## What I've found

`fluent-ffmpeg` offers either `pipe()` or `saveToFile()`.

What I figured is that when I use the `saveToFile()` function and actually save my stream into an mp3 file, it works, I do get the album cover.

But when I pipe the stream to front-end or even into a file, the song is saved properly into a file but **without** the album cover.

## Here is my code

#### Back-end (NodeJS)

```
let video = ytdl(`http://youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId}`, {
  filter: (format) => format.container === 'mp4' && format.audioEncoding,
  quality: 'lowest'
});

let stream = new FFmpeg()
  .input(video)
  .addInput(`https://i.ytimg.com/vi/${videoId}/default.jpg`)
  .outputOptions([
      '-map 0:1',
      '-map 1:0',
      '-c copy',
      '-c:a libmp3lame',
      '-id3v2_version 3',
      '-metadata:s:v title="Album cover"',
      '-metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)"'
  ])
  .format('mp3');
```

And then piping it to my front-end.

```
stream.pipe(res);
stream
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log('******* Stream end *******');
    res.end.bind(res);
  })
  .on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('ERR', err);
    res.status(500).end.bind(res);
  });
```

#### Front-end (React)

```
axios.get(url)
  .then(res => {
    axios(`${url}/download`, {
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'blob'
    })
      .then(stream => {
        const file = new Blob(
          [stream.data],
          { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
        //Build a URL from the file
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('ERROR', err);
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('ERROR', err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems there is no possible solution to complete this task with streams. I've researched a lot but found only an explanation of why we can't do this with FFmpeg and piping stream. njoyard wrote the following:

> Actually this problem is not specific to Windows. Most formats write
> stream information (duration, bitrate, keyframe position...) at the
> beginning of the file, and thus ffmpeg can only write this information
> when its output is seekable (because it has to finish processing
> streams to the end before knowing what to write). Pipes are not
> seekable, so you won't get this information when using an output pipe.
>
> As for your note about the output format, ffmpeg determines the output
> format from the output file extension, which is not possible with
> pipes; that's why you have to specify the output format explicitly.

Here is a link to find it by yourself: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/159

So, the only solution I see is saving file with saveToFile() method and attaching it to response.